# Ignite How eviction, expiry and rebalancing work with external CacheStore

Tags: ignite, gridgain

Ignite documentation explains clearly they automatically handles cache data rebalancing whern toplogy changes to keep the data evenly distributed within the cluster.

If I use CacheStore (https://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.9/docs/persistent-store) to persist cache entries with MySQL for example, will cache eviction/expiration happens even from my RDBMS ?

Example, I have a LRU eviction policy for cache size greater than 10. So will Ignite remove old entries even from my database also to keep most recent 10 entries ?  For expiry, will it remove from database too ?

Comment: Ignite expiration policy will not remove entries from database, only memory.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of these mechanisms - eviction, expiry and rebalancing - have anything to do with CacheStore.

Eviction and expiry control how many entries are present in the Ignite cache based on the number and age of the entries. If an entry is expired/evicted it is not reflected in the backing DB.

Rebalancing changes where the cache data is physically located. It will not delete any data - not in the cache, not in the backing DB.

Comment: Understood. But if I use native persistence(as I know, only limited to disk) with ignite 2.x, will expiry/eviction works on disk ?

Comment: No. Persistence is supposed to store data indefinitely, and expiry/eviction are needed to save main memory, not disk space.

Comment: If a key is missing in RAM, isn't ignite goes to disk to read it ? If so, there can be inconsistent cache with persistence model. Because an entry can be evicated/expired in RAM, but it can be in disk. How a user handles such case ? Because it's Ignite who directly deal with the disk, not the Ignite API user.

Comment: I am sorry, my previous comment about the native persistence was not correct. As you've guessed, native persistence actually works differently, and expired entries are removed from persistence. Double-checked that in a sandbox.

Comment: Thanks for the followup. cache.remove(key) will remove it from disk also. But the same does not apply for expiry. Suppose you 
- created a cache with 1min created expiry policy,
- start the JVM and check the key, it's there.
- Wait for 1min and see it's gone. Perfectly fine until now.
- Restart JVM. Now, given it's persistence enabled, I expected cache.get(key) == null. But it's not the case. It works only when JVM is running, and key is there forever in the JVM. 

Isn't this pretty inconsistent ? If someone restart JVM, he could get expired data.